# PyQt GUI Refresh

Tags: python, pyqt, refresh, pyqt5

i have a problem with my qt GUI.
I want to update/refresh my GUI every secound, and if there is an element in a list, to add a new textline or a new button. Seen much posts about threading and qtimer but not really understand it for my GUI. So i want to update everything or just want to add the new one and if the call hang up it have to be deleted.just added the code without the trys of refreshing, because they dont work how they have to ^^. would help me alot if you can help me :)
Thanks

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5 import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    import time
    import CTI
    import APIConnect



    class Fenster(QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.initMe()

        def initMe(self):
            i = 1
            box = QVBoxLayout(self)
            self.setLayout(box)
            Rufnummer = 0
            result = APIConnect.list_users()
            anrufe = APIConnect.anrufe()
            for e in result:
                self.User = box.addWidget(QPushButton(e[6]+"\n"+e[7]))
            box.addStretch(1)
            self.setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 750)
            self.setWindowTitle("CTI")
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("telefon.png"))
            self.show()

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Fenster()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def initMe(self):
    i = 1
    box = QVBoxLayout(self)
    self.setLayout(box)
    Rufnummer = 0
    result = APIConnect.list_users()
    anrufe = APIConnect.anrufe()
    for e in result:
        self.User = box.addWidget(QPushButton(e[6]+"\n"+e[7]))
    box.addStretch(1)
    self.setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 750)
    self.setWindowTitle("CTI")
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("telefon.png"))
    #---------------add this--------------------
    self.__timer = QTimer()
    self.__timer.timeout.connect(self.ontimeout)
    self.__timer.start(1000)
    #-------------------------------------------
    self.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

create a QTimer and invoke this slot

```
def ontimeout(self):
    curLayout = self.layout()
    widgetItem = curLayout.takeAt(0)
    while widgetItem != None:
        curLayout.removeWidget(widgetItem.widget())
        widgetItem = curLayout.takeAt(0)
        result = APIConnect.list_users()
    for e in result:
        curLayout.addWidget(QPushButton(e[6]+"\n"+e[7]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should init your layout before invoke self.layout(), for example you can create a QVBoxLayout in your **init** function, In addition, I think you can change

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

to

```
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(Fenster, self).__init__(parent)
    vl = QVBoxLayout()
    self.setLayout(vl)
```